# Django formTypeError: signupinfoform.Meta.fields cannot be a string

Tags: django

I created the model with the below fields and it is raising ann error as TypeError: signupinfoform.Meta.fields cannot be a string. Did you mean to type: 
('confirm_password',)?

```
 from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    # Create your models here.
    class signup(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from . models import signup

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class signupform(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password','email')
class signupinfoform(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = signup
        fields = ('confirm_password')
```

Comment: post the form as the error is in the form and not the model

Comment: Note that the error message not only told you what was wrong but showed you exactly how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class signupform(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password','email',) -> add , to make a tuple
class signupinfoform(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = signup
        fields = ('confirm_password',) -> add , to make a tuple
```

or use `list`

like

```
fields = ['confirm_password']
```

without the `,` at the end of the `()` is treated as a string